# Wordpress migration from http to https causing CSS files not loading

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to move my wordpress site from `http` to `https://`

These are the things I did

1. From admin panel changed the url from `http://example.com` to `https://example.com`
2. Took a db dump and replaced all `http://example.com` to `https://example.com`

Still some of the CSS files are loading with `http://**` as seen in the below image. Any pointers which file I need to change these urls to https ?

[image]

This is my .htaccess if that matters

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

In the short time, you can install this plugin ([Really Simple SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/)) to make all things (images, CSS, JS) works. When you have time, check if your CSS, JS is loaded dynamic or hardcoded. If it's hardcoded, changes all to dynamic and uninstall above plugin.

If you not have enough of time or don't have exprience, keep that plugin as no harm.

Comment: I installed Really Simple SSL but still mixed contents are not loading, Site is loading via https but js and css loads via http://